# entity framework, centralize exception handling

Tags: entity-framework, exception

My exception handlings are scattered among various forms. Since I need detailed exception handling the code is a little more complex like:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
   var conn = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.Connection as   
                                                          EntityConnection;
   if (conn.ConnectionString.IndexOf(Providers.SqlCe4) >= 0)
   {
     #region deal with exceptions

     Exception e = ex;
     SqlCeException sce = null;
     while (e != null)
     {
        sce = e.InnerException as SqlCeException;
        if (sce != null) break;
           e = e.InnerException;
     }
     if (sce != null)
     {
        SqlCeError = sce;
        switch (sce.NativeError)
        {
           case 25016:
              SaveErrorMessage = Localization.Texts.SqlCeException25016;
              break;
     ...
```

Instead of copy & paste every time I query or save changes, how can I centralize exception handling in one place? Is it good approach to create partial class of my DbContext/ObjectContext, and do all quering and save changes there, and handle exceptions?

Comment: You could put all code in the catch in a static utility class that receives the exception and the connection string as parameters.

Comment: Nice idea. A class called something like DbExceptionHandler, which has Handle(Exception e) method, may be.